# Initializing DataTable and destroying DataTable taking long time

Tags: datatables, knockout-3.0

I have more than 10000 records in my JSON, which I want to show in the Jquery DataTable. Destroying and recreating the table takes more than 10 sec for each function.

Can someone help me optimize the DataTable population,  or have any suggestions?

```js
VMSearchDevice.searchGridListIndividual([]); // Observable binded with the datatable
_dtSearchGrid.clear(); //Clears the Table content
_dtSearchGrid.destroy(); //Destroys the table object
VMSearchDevice.searchGridListIndividual(jsonResult); //Populating the observable array
_dtSearchGrid = $('#dtSearchResult').DataTable({ //Intializing the table again
    responsive: true,
    "sDom": 'Rlfrtip',
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bSortClasses": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" // To Set Pagination
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "bDeferRender" feature of DataTables:

Deferred rendering can provide DataTables with a huge speed boost when you are using an Ajax or JS data source for the table. This option, when set to true, will cause DataTables to defer the creation of the table elements for each row until they are needed for a draw - saving a significant amount of time.

```
"bDeferRender": true
```